# BufferedReader was never closed, but file was able to delete

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, java-io

Recently, I reviewed our application code, and I found one issue in our code.

```
/**
 * truncate cat tree(s) from the import file
 */
private void truncateCatTreesInFile(File file, String userImplCode) throws Exception
 {
     String rowStr = null, treeCode = null;
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     rowStr = reader.readLine(); // skip 1st row - header
     Impl impl;
     List<String> row = null;
     Set<String> truncatedTrees = new HashSet<String>();
     while ((rowStr = reader.readLine()) != null)
     {
         row = CrudServiceHelper.getRowFromFile(rowStr);
         if (row == null) continue;

         impl = getCatImportImpl(row.get(ECatTreeExportImportData.IMPL.getIndex()), userImplCode);
         treeCode = row.get(ECatTreeExportImportData.TREE_CODE.getIndex());
         if(truncatedTrees.contains(treeCode)) continue;

         truncatedTrees.add(treeCode);             
         CatTree catTree = _treeDao.findByCodeAndImpl(treeCode, impl.getId());
         if(catTree!= null) _treeDao.makeTransient(catTree);             
     }
     _treeDao.flush();   
 }
```

Looking at the above code, the "reader" was never closed, I was thinking it could be an issue, but actually, it just works fine, the file is able to delete by tomcat.

```
 javax.servlet.context.tempdir>
 [java] 2013-03-27 17:45:54,285 INFO [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatch
```

er] -

Basically, what I am trying to do is uploading one file from browser, and generate sql based on the file to insert data into our database.  After all done, delete the file.

I am surprised this code works fine, does anybody have an idea here? I tried to google it, but I did not get any idea.

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 1):

Not closing a reader may result in a resource leak. Deleting an open file may still be perfectly fine.

Under Linux (and other Unix variants) deleting a file if just unlinking a name from it. A file without any names left gets actually freed. So opening a file, deleting it (removing its name) and then reading and writing to it is a well-known way to obtain a temporary file. Once the file is closed, the space is freed, but not earlier.

Under Windows, certain programs lock files they read, this prevents other processes from removing such a file. But not all programs do so. I don't have a Windows machine around to actually test how does Java handle this.

The fact that the code does not crash does not mean that the code works completely correctly. The problem you noticed might become visible only much later, if the app just consumes more and more RAM due to the leak. This is unlikely, though: the garbage collector will eventually close readers, and probably soon enough, because `reader` is local and never leaks out of the method.

Comment: I tested it in my local windows OS, that's why I am surprised, since I knew that if any program is opening a file in windows, and any other programs try to delete this file, it will be failed. I am thinking it maybe because tomcat will release all of the resources after the servlet is released (I mean the request is finished), and the tomcat will also delete the temporary files automatically.